# Do unused xaml styles increase the size of xap file?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml

If i include a bunch of styles that i don't use any more into my project will that increase the size of the final XAP file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  It will compile into the DLL and take up space.  Since XAML is XML, ZIP compresses it well but you should take any bit of unused content out.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the compiler does not edit the Xaml resources included in XAP, it includes them as is.